# Make an object return a specific property if none is referenced

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have started creating a HTML5 canvas game. I have a basic html document with the canvas. The problem i'm facing is with the JavaScript. I have an object as my game's "controller" named `Pixels`. Within the object I have an object named `canvas` which has 1 property named `ctx` which returns the ctx of the canvas (which I'm currently getting directly from `document.getElementById("Pixels-Canvas").getContext("2d)`. The problem is: Let's say I call `Pixels.canvas.ctx` that would return the 2d context of the canvas, simple. Now let's say I call `Pixels.canvas`. How would I make that return `document.getElementById("Pixels-Canvas")`, without adding a canvas property to the canvas object, making the call like this: `Pixels.canvas.canvas`?

What I have:

```js
var Pixels =
{
  canvas:
  { 
    ctx:
    document.getElementById("Pixels-Canvas").getContext("2d")
  }
};
```

`Pixels.canvas` Which isn't what I want as it doesn't give me the canvas itself

---

What I don't want:

```js
var Pixels =
{
  canvas:
  {
    canvas:
    document.getElementById("Pixels-Canvas"),

    ctx:
    document.getElementById("Pixels-Canvas").getContext("2d")
  }
};
```

`Pixels.canvas.canvas` Returns the canvas but `canvas.canvas`? Ugly.

## NOTE

I think so far I have been misunderstood. What I want is the call `Pixels.canvas` to return the canvas and `Pixels.canvas.ctx` return the ctx of the canvas.

---

### SOLUTION

I have solved my own problem. See my answer below for details

Comment: In practice there probably won't be very many references made directly to the `<canvas>` DOM node.

Comment: True! But in this case, there will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem.

```js
var Pixels =
{
  canvas:
  document.getElementById("Pixels-Canvas"),
};

Pixels.canvas.ctx = Pixels.canvas.getContext("2d");
```

---

Now `Pixels.canvas` returns the canvas, while `Pixels.canvas.ctx` returns the context!

Comment: Well, actually `Pixels.canvas.getContext("2d")` would do it as well.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's going to be used more than a few times, thus making the code longer

Comment: This is where you can get yourself into trouble. If you are going to expose the `canvas`, then that object's `.getContext()` method will automatically be exposed through it as well.  Deciding to create another method that maps to it certainly can be done, but it's a form of unnecessary optimization because you now have two methods that are identical. It would be best to use the native one and then users of your API can cache that if they wish.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this?:

```
var Pixels = {
  canvas: document.getElementById("Pixels-Canvas"),
  ctx: this.getContext("2d")
};
```

Then, you could get the actual `canvas` DOM element with `Pixels.canvas` and the context with `Pixels.ctx`.

Comment: I like being organized and making my code readable as well as understandable. `Pixels.canvas`? Ok? `Pixels.ctx`? The application itself has a ctx?

Comment: @TastyRobot And so again I ask, what's wrong with this? It's very organized and clear as to what you will get.

Comment: Don't get me wrong your solution is perfectly fine, it's just that at some point I will have too many properties for my main object which is why I wanted to organize all the canvas properties in a canvas object

Comment: Yep, you saw it right. The `Pixels` object won't only have the property `canvas` (which is an onject) for long. I plan on adding way more stuff!

Comment: So what? Having lots of properties isn't a detriment as long as they all are clear as to what they are. It's called making an API. One of the wisest pieces of advice you'll ever get in any programming context is not to try to optimize code as you write it.

Comment: I understand. But is that efficient for readability and comprehension?

Comment: Check out how many properties there are on the `window` object, or on a jQuery object.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. As long as each property is clearly named and serves a valid purpose, having many of them is not a factor in designing an interface or API.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible, and also does not make sense to me, since it can become confusing if someone else takes your code. Best way is to specify canvas property for canvas and canvasCtx or ctx for context.

Comment: What I want is to have a canvas object for my game object because that helps me understand. I guess I will have to do that if it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pixels.canvas.ctx.canvas`.

The call to `getContext("2d")` returns a [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D), which has a [`canvas` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/canvas) that refers back to the original canvas element.

That said, I agree with Scott Marcus' recommendation.

Comment: Same for this solution, it works! But will get confusing at some point